# How to manage child select element from within a knockout js template

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, html-select

I have the following scenario, I am getting some data from the server using ko.mapping and it is translated in the form:

```
var viewModel = {
    name: "Abc",
    educations: [{ course: "C1", countryID: 1, cityID = 2},
                 { course: "C2", countryID: 2, cityID = 3}]
}
```

I also have 2 array variables, which are:

```
var countries = [{id=1,name="UAE"},{id=2,name="USA"},];
var cities = [{id=1,name="Dubai", cid=1},{id=2,name="Al-Ain", cid=1},
              {id=3,name="Newyork", cid=2},{id=4,name="Houston", cid=2},];
```

now to show / edit this data i have the following HTML

```
<div>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name"/>
    <table data-bind="template: { name: 'cet', foreach: educations }">
    </table>
</div>
<script type="text/html" id="cet">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select data-bind="options: countries, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: 'Select...', value: countryID"></select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select data-bind="options: cities, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: 'Select...', value: cityID"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Now what I need is that when data is sent from the server, the select boxes should show the correct items corresponding to the bound objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Solved it :)

Data Bindings should be done as follows:

```
<select id="Countries" name="Countries" data-bind="options: countries, optionsText: 'CountryName', optionsValue: 'CountryID', optionsCaption: 'Select...', value: SelectedCountryID"></select>
<select id="Cities" name="Cities" data-bind="options: Cities, optionsText: 'CityName', optionsValue: 'CityID', optionsCaption: 'Select...', value: CityID"></select>
```

First i'll have to run **ko.mapping** to convert the viewModel to an "*Observable viewModel*" then the Code will be like:

```
if(viewModel.educations() != undefined && viewModel.educations().length > 0) {
    for(k in viewModel.educations()) {
        var education = viewModel.educations()[k];

        education.Cities = ko.observableArray();
        education.SelectedCountryID = ko.computed({
            read: function() {
                return(this.CountryID());
            },
            write: function(value) {
                this.CountryID(value);
                this.Cities.removeAll();

                if(value != undefined) {
                    for(c in cities) {
                        if(cities[c].cid == value) {
                            this.Cities.push(cities[c]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            owner: education,
        });

        if(viewModel.educations()[k].CountryID() != 0 ||
            viewModel.educations()[k].CountryID() != undefined) {
            viewModel.educations()[k].SelectedCountryID(viewModel.educations()[k].CountryID());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've almost reached your goal -- [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RP3eR/1/) is a working version of your code.

```js
var viewModel = {
    name: "Abc",
    educations: [{course: "C1", countryID: 1, cityID: 2},
                 {course: "C2", countryID: 2, cityID: 3}],
    countries: [{id: 1, name: "UAE"}, {id: 2, name: "USA"}],
    cities: [{id: 1, name: "Dubai", cid: 1},
             {id: 2, name: "Al-Ain", cid: 1},
             {id: 3, name: "Newyork", cid: 2},
             {id: 4, name: "Houston", cid: 2}]
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: name" />
    <table data-bind="template: { name: 'cet', foreach: educations }"></table>
</div>
<script type="text/html" id="cet">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select data-bind="options: $root.countries, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: 'Select...', value: countryID"></select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select data-bind="options: $root.cities, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: 'Select...', value: cityID"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Comment: Thx Dmitry but the code snippet you've sent me is not working correctly. If you check the JSFiddle link you will see in the output window that the child dropdown is containing ALL the elements of the cities not only the ones associated with the parent select.

Comment: I have however solved this. and will be posting an answer to my own question :)